# Loop through each row and grade the customer

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to loop through my dataframe and add a grade to company members in the `Mbr grade` column. One condition is based in the amount they spend, and the other is based in the number of transactions they have.

```
def MbrGrade():
    for index, row in MbrKPI.iterrows():    
        if MbrKPI['Amt']>500 & MbrKPI['Transaction No_']>10:
            MbrKPI['Mbr grade']='A'
        elif MbrKPI['Amt']>500 & MbrKPI['Transaction No_']<10:
            MbrKPI['Mbr grade']='B'
        elif MbrKPI['Amt']<500 & MbrKPI['Transaction No_']<10:
            MbrKPI['Mbr grade']='C'
    MbrGrade()
```

When I run the above function, it gave me the error below:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `np.where`

```
MbrKPI = pd.DataFrame([
        [501, 11],
        [501,  9],
        [499,  9]
    ], columns=['Amt', 'Transaction No_'])

a = MbrKPI['Amt'].values
t = MbrKPI['Transaction No_'].values
MbrKPI['MbrGrade'] = np.where(a > 500, np.where(t > 10, 'A', 'B'), 'C')

MbrKPI
```

[image]

---

***note:***
you don't address `<500 & >10` so I ignored it.
you should be able to adapt accordingly.
***note2:***
also, take care of edge cases `==500` and `==10`

Answer (score 1):

I endorse [piRSquared's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41174811/240490) and warnings about the gaps in your conditions. The `np.where` approach is nicely compact and well-vectorized.

It may be a little hard to see why it works for someone new to pandas, however. So  here is an approach that tracks normal Python logic and forms. It's not nearly so well-vectorized--but unless you have very large datasets, that's probably a non-issue.

```py
def decide_grade(row):        
    amt, trans = row['Amt'], row['Transaction No_']
    if amt > 500 and trans > 10: return 'A' 
    if amt > 500 and trans < 10: return 'B' 
    if amt < 500 and trans < 10: return 'C' 
    return '???'

MbrKPI['Grade'] = MbrKPI.apply(decide_grade, axis=1)
```

It uses a decision function, `decide_grade`, to separate the logic of deciding on a grade from the indexing and row creation code. The `axis=1` means that the function being applied gets each row of the `DataFrame` in turn (the default, `axis=0`, passes each column in turn). The decision function then "destructures" the row values into two scalar variables so that its decision logic can be stated in the simplest, clearest way possible.

With a larger dataset, the results:

[image]

Whichever path you choose, please note that "loop through the rows" is, if not wrong, not the Pandas idiom. Applying a decision function, computing the new column in vector form are better-performing and more idiomatic ways to update data frames. They're much closer to database query / data manipulation statements than they are to conventional loops.

Comment: thanks! helps me understand the use of functions better